# Using L298N to control DC Motor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, h-bridge

I am developing a system where I want to control the direction of the DC motor (12V) from Arduino Mega/Uno. For that, I am using L298N H-bridge chip without the board as shown below. [image: L298N]

My question is, do I need to add extra hardware or is it enough on its own?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already read the L298 datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this particular device should work on its own.  However you should search for and read the datasheet for it. (I'll leave you to do that yourself, just to make sure you really do read it.)

You should consider a heatsink too by the way, and provision for things like a fuse on the power, and whether you will be using a separate 5V for the logic (again you need the datasheet for that).